# When does this Java Thread stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am just wondering that when the `timer` function finishes does the thread stop? or is there anything special I have to do to stop it?

```
public void testing() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(this) {
                timer();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

public void timer() {
    boolean active = true;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

    while (active) {
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

        if (finish - start >= 20) {
            System.out.println("Finished");
            active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it will stop. You could `join()` the `Thread` if you want to wait for the `Thread` to stop.

Comment: Just a side note:  There is virtually never a good reason to synchronize the run() method of a thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by definition, a thread stops executing when its `run()` method (or the `run()` method of its runnable, when constructed from a Runnable) returns.